# Angularjs dependency injection of an instantiable class

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, code-injection

I am trying to learn a little about AngularJS. I have created websites in ASP.NET before so I decided to try to create an AngularJS site with MVC. I downloaded this excellent example:
https://github.com/jph00/AngularTutorial/tree/master/AngularTutorial
I created my own site based upon it but I have a problem with the dependency injection in the AngularJS code.
I created a class called Hotel

```
public class Hotel
{

    public int HotelId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

In the AngularJS code I have a file called Emp.js

```
    var HotelApp = angular.module('HotelApp', ['ngResource']).

HotelApp.factory('Hotel', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/Hotel/:HotelId', { HotelId: '@HotelId' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });});
```

I also have HotelApp declared in the div tag of the page where I need it;

```
<div ng-app="HotelApp" data-ng-controller="hotelController" class="container">
```

However when I set breakpoints and jump to them, **Hotel** is always undefined. The only difference between the GitHub example and my project is that my project uses cshtml (the GitHub example is html).
I have not seen many examples online of dependency injection with AngularJS but those I have seen don't use instantiable classes (as my example has). Is there any example out there of AngularJS like this (dependency injection in an MVC project using a class)?

**Edit:this is the Controller class;**

```
{
public class HotelController : ApiController
{
    private HotelsContext db = new HotelsContext();
    // GET api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Hotel> Get()         
    {
        return db.Hotels.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public Hotel Get(int id)
    {
        Hotel hotel = db.Hotels.Find(id);
        if (hotel == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return hotel;
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Hotels.Add(hotel);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, hotel);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = hotel.HotelId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public HttpResponseMessage PutHotel(int id, Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        if (id != hotel.HotelId)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        db.Entry(hotel).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        Hotel hotel = db.Hotels.Find(id);
        if (hotel == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        db.Hotels.Remove(hotel);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, hotel);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

The AngularJS controller is;

```
function hotelController($scope, $http) {  
$scope.loading = true;
$scope.addMode = false;

//Used to display the data
$http.get('/api/Hotel/').success(function (data) {        
    $scope.hotels = data;
    $scope.loading = false;
})
.error(function () {
    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while loading posts!";
    $scope.loading = false;
});

$scope.toggleEdit = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Hotel) {
    alert("Edit 1");
    $scope.action = "Update";
    alert("Edit 2");
    id = $scope.HotelId;
    alert("id is " + id);

    // $scope.item = Todo.get({ id: id });
    this.hotel.editMode = !this.hotel.editMode;

};
//Used to save a record after edit
$scope.save = function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Hotel) {
    alert("scope item");
    alert("Hotel " + Hotel.id);
    $scope.item = Hotel.get({ id: id });
    alert("scope.item" );
    Hotel.update({ id: id }, $scope.item, function () {
       // $location.path('/');
        alert("id is " + id);
    });
};


//Used to add a new record
$scope.add = function () {        
    $scope.loading = true;
    $http.post('/api/Hotel/', this.newhotel).success(function (data) {
        alert("Added Successfully!!");
        $scope.addMode = false;
        $scope.hotels.push(data);
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Adding Friend! " + data;
        $scope.loading = false;

    });
};

//Used to edit a record
$scope.deletefriend = function () {       
    $scope.loading = true;
    var friendid = this.hotel.FriendId;
    $http.delete('/api/Hotel/' + friendid).success(function (data) {
        alert("Deleted Successfully!!");
        $.each($scope.hotels, function (i) {
            if ($scope.hotels[i].FriendId === friendid) {
                $scope.hotels.splice(i, 1);
                return false;
            }
        });
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).error(function (data) {
        $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving Friend! " + data;
        $scope.loading = false;

    });
};
```

}

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: I just added it to the end now

Comment: Post angularjs controller not mvc.

Comment: I just added the angularjs controller now

Comment: take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved for me. The problem was the controller function had to be changed to get a reference to the Hotel class. 
It was

function hotelController($scope, $http) {

but is now

```
function hotelController($scope, Hotel) {
```

If anybody needs further clarification contact me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your controller and pass Hotel as a dependency.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/t7rhe9V5KN0d3ovmapuu?p=preview)**

```
var HotelApp = angular.module('HotelApp', []);

HotelApp.factory('Hotel', [function() {
    return {
        run: function() {
            alert("run");
        }
    }
}]);

HotelApp.controller("hotelController", ["$scope", "Hotel",
  function($scope, Hotel) {
      Hotel.run();
  }
]);
```

[Good read on dependency injection in angular.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/dependency-injection.html)

**EDIT:**

Remove $scope, $location, $routeParams and Hotel parameters. You need to add those as dependency in your controller like in the example above.

```
$scope.toggleEdit = function($scope, $location, $routeParams, Hotel) {
   alert("Edit 1");
   $scope.action = "Update";
   alert("Edit 2");
   id = $scope.HotelId;
   alert("id is " + id);

   // $scope.item = Todo.get({ id: id });
   this.hotel.editMode = !this.hotel.editMode;
```

};

```
//Used to save a record after edit
$scope.save = function($scope, $location, $routeParams, Hotel) {
   alert("scope item");
   alert("Hotel " + Hotel.id);
   $scope.item = Hotel.get({ id: id });
   alert("scope.item");
   Hotel.update({ id: id }, $scope.item, function() {
      // $location.path('/');
         alert("id is " + id);
       });
 };
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code but "Hotel" is still 'undefined' when I hover the mouse over it. When I put $scope in the Immediate window I can get at the properties of that, just not Hotel

Comment: Thank you for the link. The example in it is similar to what I have seen before: "myFactory" is injected (with .factory) but I don't see what "myFactory" is. My equivalent is Hotel which is a class with properties.

Comment: In your code, when I set a breakpoint on              "HotelApp.factory('Hotel', [function () and hit F11, it jumps into the middle of angular.min.js. In the example on GitHub  https://github.com/jph00/AngularTutorial/tree/master/AngularTutorial) on the equivalent line (.factory) it jumps into this line in angular.js: invokeQueue[insertMethod || 'push']([provider, method, arguments]);

Comment: make sure factory and controller are in same module or if they are in different then inject that module in root module.

Comment: When you say the same module do you mean the file (.js file) or the same folder?

Comment: No, for example you defined HotelApp Module, now if you define another module just for controller names angular.module("HotelApp.Controllers", []) then you have to include that module in HotelApp module angular.module('HotelApp', ["HotelApp.Controllers"]);

Comment: Thanks for all your help but I still can't get it to work.I am going to post it to freelancer and I will post it on here if I get it to work.